# Python annotations for class returned

Tags: python, annotations

How to annotate this code ?

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

def get_foo_class() -> ???:
    return Foo

def get_foo_instance() -> Foo:
    return Foo()

def give_me_foo_class(class_: ???) -> None:
    # class should be Foo class
    pass
```

I can replace `???` by `Foo`, but how to differenciate instance type than instance of this type ?

Comment: If you're returning a class object, it's an instance of `type`.

Comment: We cannot be more precise ? Annotation will be exact but not very usefull.